# How to play youtube video within the application in iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, youtube, uiwebview, youtube-api

I am building an ionic/cordova application where I want to play video from Youtube live video. I am using YouTube API.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").css({"background-color": "yellow", "font-size": "200%"});
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="player"></div>

<script src="youtube.js"></script>

<script>

    // create youtube player
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '200',
          width: '200',
          videoId: '0Bmhjf0rKe8',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }

    // autoplay video
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    // when video ends
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
        if(event.data === 0) {            
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
            }, 2000);
        }
    }

</script>

<div id='elementtoScrollToID' class='my_div'>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Using this code i have created an **iPhone application using cordova**.

**Now when I click on youtube video its playing the video with the default player i.e. quicktime player. Its not running the video within the UIWebview frame itself(Inside my Div). But I want to show the video in the 1st half of the screen i.e my UIWebview frame. Is that possible?**

In my App is shows like,
**when clicking on red play button I can see the video in full screen in quicktime player like this:**

[image][image]

**But I want to show the video within the same webView frame not via quick time player. It should play like this:**

[image]

Is there any other way to achieve the same? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

In Android its working perfectly.. :-)

Comment: This link may help you https://github.com/jv17/YoutubePlayer

Comment: @Sachin: Am using Cordova application using HTML5 and javascript and the given  YoutubePlayer code is completely for ObjC developers. :-(

Comment: @Sachin: Hi Guys.. am also searching for a solution. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you get this to work?